# panel redrawing on scroll

Tags: c#, panel

I have a panel that adds a a bunch of linklabels in it.  When I scroll the panel, it is calling the paint event.  Is there any way to disable it from calling the paint event on scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to need to clear the controls before calling the draw event